# How to save blob and play it with wavesurfer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, wavesurfer.js

I'm creating a chat application where audio messages can be recorded.

I am creating blobs using react-mic. This is where i run into problems.

Can i just stringify the blob, save it to my DB and then pull it, reverse it and play it with Wavesurfer?

Also I dont think i'm really thinking about this the right way, because the blob:URL is always a local host adress?

Comment: did you tried it ?

Comment: Oh. yes. it doesnt work. Wavesurfer cant load the audio file.

Comment: is there any alternative packages instead of wavesurfer

Answer (score 1):

Use the "loadBlob" method to play the audio directly.

If you want to store the audio file for later use, simply add a reference URL in your db  that points to the audio file within CDN.

Heres how my AudioPlayer component defines how to load the audioData

```
 wavesurfer.current = WaveSurfer.create(options);

  if (!audioData) return;

  if (typeof audioData === "string") {
    wavesurfer.current.load(audioData); // must be a URL
  } else {
    wavesurfer.current.loadBlob(audioData); //must be a Blob
  }
```